# Crashing after using OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-activity, onclicklistener

I tried switching activities with an OnClickListener but as soon as I use the code the app isn't even starting and it immediately crashes. The "View.OnClickListener()" is also not colored but AndroidStuido only tells me that I can use a lambda and not that it is not used.
Any advice on why it crashes? As soon as I "comment out" the OnClickListener-Part the app totally works.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button confirm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonConfirm);
        confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { openSSO();}
            });
          }

   public void openSSO() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SingleStockOverview.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I've deleted some of the code in between because I don't think it's needed to solve the problem.

Comment: Post the full stacktrace of the crash. The lambda warning is just telling you that you can simplify the argument passed to setOnClickListener as a lambda.

Comment: We might need to see `activity_main.xml`, looks like your button can't be found.

Comment: perhaps, the button id in your xml is not the same as you defined in your activity class. Another possibility is that you have a mistake in defining the object or maybe you call the button id from another XML.

Comment: I am working with a BottomNavigationBar so i got my Button assigned in a Fragment (not the activity_main.xml. It's a different .xml file. Is this a problem? Can i only use things which are assigned in the activity_main.xml from the MainActivity.java? If yes, does someone got a tip how I make those buttons in the fragments work while still using the BottomNavigationBar? I am pretty confused now

Comment: The button is coloured, so i used the right one. But when i want to assign a new OnClickListener, the Listener is grey and not coloured.

Comment: Make sure you are using correct id and Button in your xml. for better understanding share your xml here.